# many CardView inside a HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, horizontalscrollview

[image]

I want make screen like that.
May be It must use HorizontalScrollView and CardView.

[image]

I make here using CardView.
But It needs more CardView.

I try that, may be HorizontalScrolView can put only 1 CardView.

In HorizontalScrollView, How to put CardView more?

I'm sorry I'm not fluent in English.

Comment: Why don't you  use recyclerView?

Comment: recyclerView..? I heard that first. I will search now. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use Recycler view instead

```
 mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
```

> and add more cards using adapter